# convert byte to binary

Tags: c#, flv

I have FLV file I stored it to byte array and I can read it byte by byte.
I want to convert each byte to binary 0s and 1s

I want to convert variable b to binary 1s 0s. for example if b = 70 how to convert it to binary

what function I can use in C# to do this??

here is my code to read FLV file and store it byte array.

```
byte[] myArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"myFlvFile.flv");

int r = 0;
foreach (var b in myArray)
{
  r += 1;
  txtBit.Text = Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(b);

  if (r == 50)
    return;
}
```

Comment: There are 8 bits in a byte, so you can't convert a byte into a bit without loosing most of the information. Can you post _examples_ of what you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by “binary”? String containing binary representation of that byte?

Comment: I want to convert variable b to binary 1s 0s. for example if b = 70 how to convert it to binary.

Comment: @Eyla: it already _is_ binary. What are you asking for, exactly?

Comment: @John and others. He/she just wants a bit-string etc. `"01010101"`.

Comment: @John Saunders  I just want to convert b to 0s and 1s and I got the answer thank you,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a bit-string:

```
byte b = 100;

//Will be "1100100"
var bitstring = Convert.ToString(b, 2);
```

so in your example, just add `, 2`

The second argument is the base you want to use.

- 2 = binary (0 - 1)
- 8 = octal (0 - 7)
- 16 = hex (0 - F)

and secondary, I have a little improvement on your code :) this will do:

```
byte[] myArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"myFlvFile.flv");

for (r = 0; r < 50; r++)
{
    txtBit.Text = Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(myArray[r], 2);
    //Or if you want to append instead of replace? (I think you do, but that is not what your code do)
    txtBit.Text += Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(myArray[r], 2);
}
```

there is still stuff to improve on - you may want to look at `StringBuilder` or similar :-) (it is quite inefficient to concatenate the text the way you do it.)

Comment: @Timwi Thanks for correcting my flawed code (`b` should be `myArray[r]`) :)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use BitArray class.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\yourfile.flv");
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);

for (int counter = 0; counter < bits.Length; counter++)
{
    Console.Write(bits[counter] ? "1" : "0");
    if ((counter + 1) % 8 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and you will get something like this:

```
10000110
10110110
00001110
01011100
00000100
00001100
```

Obviously, using BitArray is quite ineffective for large files, so if you need to decode long files, use bit binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BitArray Class in .net

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   BitArray myBA3 = new BitArray( myBytes );
```

for more information see below post

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this example program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string filename = @"D:\Temp\dcs_0002.jpg";

        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        var value = BytesAsBinaryString(fileBytes, 50);

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public static string BytesAsBinaryString(IEnumerable<byte> bytes, int howMany)
    {
        var binaryStrings = from b in bytes 
                      select Convert.ToString(b, 2);
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, binaryStrings.Take(howMany));
    }
}
```